# phpmyadmin, xampp, wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I just got my first Macbook and tried to setup xampp.

I setup a table and added a password for root@localhost.

After that I added the password in `config.inc.ph`p I couldn't access `phpmyadmin` anymore.

I found several suggestions and modified the permissions again

> (chmod 644, 755, added $cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;)

but nothing worked.

Now I deleted and reinstalled xampp and got instantly the same error.

First install was

> xampp-osx-5.6.8-0-installer

second:

> xampp-osx-5.5.24-0

Answer (score 10):

It could be that your config.inc.php file for phpmyadmin is *"world writable"*.

- Go to **xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php**
- Right click **config.inc.php** go to *Get info*
- Click the lock to enable editing permissions
- Enter password
- Set all permissions to read-only, except for the admin

That should solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Search for the file Config.class.php
2. Find(cmd+F) checkpermissions
3. Comment the following code

   ```
   /*if (!($perms === false) && ($perms & 2)) {
       // This check is normally done after loading configuration
       $this->checkWebServerOs();
       if ($this->get('PMA_IS_WINDOWS') == 0) {
           $this->source_mtime = 0;
           PMA_fatalError(
               __(
                   'Wrong permissions on configuration file, '
                   . 'should not be world writable!'
               )
           );
       }
   }*/
   ```
4. Save and try again - localhost/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

To solve this it means your config.inc.php file is read and writable to everyone
which is not acceptable
to change it back to read only

Note: you must have mount the folder first by following the blog content below

https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20170628.html

click on the terminal tab on your xampp interface
once the terminal open paste below command

```
chmod 644 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

which is chmod 644 is use to change file sharing & permission rule to read only
which is required before you can access http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Update these two files "**Permission**" as below

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/**config.inc.php**
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/**my.cnf**

1. Right click and go to "Get info".
2. Unlock editing by clicking the lock icon bottom right.
3. Set all permissions to read-only, except for the admin.

Now it should works fine :)